# what to choose betweeen #num, [(ngModel)]="num" and [value]="num" in angularjs 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

In an input text field I have to take the value and use it in my .ts file.
can you suggest me which of the following syntax should be used for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want synchronous alignement between what you see in text field and what you have in the variable use

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="num">
```

If you want to show in text input field the value of `num` property and align `num` property with the value of text field at certain events (e.g. change) then use

```
<input type="text" [value]="num" (change)="onNameChange($event)">
```

I hope this helps